# Yii Framework & user authentication

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I am new to MVC, just a few doubt

1. I think "attributeLabels" should belongs to VIEW.

   Because it is not a logic rule of data, It's about presentation of data.

   [image]

   ---
2. I wonder why the login and authenticate is put in MODEL is good idea.

   I will consider that there should be only one design of "How to login" or "What will you check when user login" in the whole site. I am not sure, but I feels like the Customization of "login and authenticate"  should be some where out of MCV, like "protected/config/main.php". Or separate in someWhere. login and authenticate in MODEL quite strange in my concept.

   [image]

Comment: Please paste the actual code instead of the image of your code. It might help for someone to use the code in an answer instead of having to retype it.

Comment: if you start reading the documents carefully again, you will notice that Yii supports two types of models, ActiveRecord, and Form. It will therefore make sense to place the attributes in the form model. Personally, I just combine them.

Comment: crafter, I am not sure you are replying to my question. I am not saying about attributes. and it is not about code, that image is just a examplate.

Comment: I hear you. Understand that there is a corresponding call to login() and/or authenticate() that originates from a controller (typically). If you consider that the storage mechanism for the security apparatus is unknown to the controller, and that the storage and retrieval of security related information is left up to the model (eg, Do I read from the db, or LDAP, or session, or oAuth,...), then the above approach might make sense. If you look carefully at the code (image) you pasted, you will see that the actual validation logic happens in the UserIdentity{} class.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you put the attributeLabels in view, then every time u create a view (create,edit etc) using that model, u need to define the labels each time. Anyway there are ways to give label names in view. And it's not only in yii, in asp.net mvc, the name is also defined in model.
2. The login username,password comes from the query through the database models. So u need a controller and view for LoginForm.php. This is a reason to put it in models i believe.

Comment: Yes, the username,password can be comes from database, in that case  you will need Model. But I am talking about the function customization of login and authenticate .

Comment: when a model is created, it is given the rules, functions, attributes and etc that it can perform. U can call a function from the model such as:"model_name::model->function_name" if it's needed. Btw, u can create your own customized authentication and put it somewhere else;it should work i think.